# Error on starting a new project on android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android. I started an new project project in android studio 3.0 but after Gradle build error is shown as:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for  
    ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': 
        Could not resolve 
           javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
```

[Screen Shot of android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6bNM.png)

```
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidlife.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
}`
```

Comment: show me your app's `build.gradle`

Comment: plz check the build.gradle

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: I ust changed minSDK from 15 to 24 
All errors has gone

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog has the answer to your question.

> > > I’ve seen your error caused in environments that have somewhat restrictive network connections.

[check this out](https://community.blackberry.com/thread/110452)